# How to work with literal square bracket using awk and foreach iterations

Tags: awk, sed, foreach, csh

I have a file named `mapstring`. Because of `[` string in my patterns my script is not working. Please help me find a solution to this.

#### Content of mapstring

```
BC1 bc1
BC2 bc2
BAD_BIT[0]  badl0
BAD_BIT[1]  badlleftnr
```

I am working with following script to replace pattern in file testfile

#### Content of script

```
foreach cel (`cat mapstring |awk '{print $1}'`)
    echo $cel
    grep -wq $cel testfile
    if( $status == 0 ) then
        set var2 = `grep -w $cel rajeshmap |awk '{print $2}'`
        sed -i "s% ${cel} % ${var2} %g" testfile
    endif
end
```

#### Content of testfile

```
 rajesh jain BAD_BIT[0] 1234 BAD_BIT[1000]
 jain rajesh DA[0] snps
 raj jain CLK stm
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because square brackets are reserved in sed's [basic regex syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

You'll have to escape them (and any other special characters in fact) using backslashes (i.e. `\[`) before using them later in your script;  this can itself be done with sed, e.g.:

```
sed  -re 's/(\[|\])/\\\1/g'
```

(note that using extended regexes in sed (`-r`) can make this easier).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
# or sh

sed 's/[[\\$^&.+*]/\\&/g' mapstring | while read -r OldCel NewCel
 do
    echo ${OldCel}
    sed -i "/${OldCel}/ {
      s/.*/ & /;s% ${OldCel} % ${NewCel} %g;s/.\\(.*\\)./\\1/
      }" testfile
 done
```

pre escape your cel values for a sed manipulation (you could add other special char if occuring and depending directive given to sed like `{(` )

try something like this (*cannot test, no GNU sed available here*)

From the good remarq of @tripleee, this need to be another shell than the one used in the request, script adapted for this

Comment: There's a spurious `endif` and I'm not sure if this is valid Csh `while` syntax (it's been a while ... sic).

Comment: sorry for the endif, not part of this script and result of partial unwanted copy paste. I modify the post

Comment: I still get `while: Expression syntax` when I try this in `tcsh`.  While I hope and believe that the OP can use Bourne shell instead, it does not fix the immediate problem in the OP's environment.

Comment: why tcsh, i don't see any mention about this shell specifically ? I test (with sed without -i) on ksh and sh and work (i had to add the `-r` on read)

Comment: The OP's code is clearly not in `sh`/`ksh`/`bash` syntax.  With a proper `#!/bin/sh` shebang, your script should certainly work there as well, but does not really address how to fix the OP's code.

Comment: ok, you got the point, i adapt the code to a more adequat shell for th script

Answer (score 0):

Your script is rather inefficient anyhow.  You can simply get rid of `csh` entirely (along with the useless `cat` and the other stylistic problems), and do this with two connected `sed` scripts.

```
sed 's/[][*\\%]/\\&/g;s/\([^ ]*\) *\(.*\)/s%\1%\2%g/' mapstring |
sed -i -f - testfile
```

This is assuming your `sed` can accept a script on standard input (`-f -`) and that your `sed` dialect does not understand any additional special characters which need to be escaped.